# grails Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) when url parameter contains angle bracket

Tags: grails

the exception is：
 Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.

the request url: http://localhost:8080/auth/index?param1=<

and then throws

```
ceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL if it contains special characters which has special meaning in programming language like groovy.

Encode URL as follows

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
String url = "http://localhost:8080/auth/index?param1=<";   
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
println encodedUrl​ 
redirect(url: encodedUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the return keyword if you use redirect it is not the last statement in the method.

Grails by default uses the last statement as the return statement. If you redirect and it is the last statement, it works automagically. But this is not the case if you use return in an if-statement and return is not the last statement. In these case you have to explicitly use the return keyword.

```
def someAction(){
     if(someCondition == true){
          redirect action: "anotherAction"
          return                  // this prevents the execution of the code below
     }else{
        // do something else 
     } 

     redirect action: "myAction"  // this will throw an error if the condition above matched and it redirected without return keyword
}
```